# Run function after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a live filter by category and letter so you can filter a list of items with both of them.

[image]

Everything works as expected, except for the following:

When a category is clicked, the items that are not from that category, are hidden. Because some items are not longer being displayed, the idea is to hide the letters that are no longer needed

For some reason is hiding the letters from the previous clicked category, not from the current one.

So for example, if I click Social and then Active, under the Active filter will display the letters available on the Social filter

```
<div id="org_letterfilter"></div>

<ul class="organisation_list">
     <!-- Example of one of the elements of the list -->
     <li id="a">
          <a class="gl-link" href="#">A Society</a>
          <dl class="gl-attributes">
               <dt class="gl-attributeset">Category</dt>
               <dd class="gl-attribute">Active</dd>
          </dl> 
     </li>
</ul>





//Filter by letter
function reload_cart() {
    var lastletter = '';
    var letters = new Array();
    $('.organisation_list li:visible .gl-link').each(function(){
        var letter = $(this).text().substr(0,1).toLowerCase();
        if (!isNaN(letter)) {
            letter = '#';
        }
        if (letter != lastletter) {
            letters.push(letter);
            lastletter = letter;
        }
        $(this).parent().attr('id', letter);
    });

    var arLen=letters.length;
    for ( var i=0, len=arLen; i<len; ++i ){
        $('#org_letterfilter').append('<a href="'+letters[i]+'">'+letters[i]+'</a>');
    }

}

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#org_letterfilter a:nth-child(1)").addClass("current");


    $('#filters li').click(function (e) {
        $("#org_letterfilter a").removeClass("current");
    });


    $('#org_letterfilter a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#org_letterfilter a").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");

        var letter = $(this).attr('href');
        var target = $('.organisation_list li:visible .gl-link').filter(function () {
            return $.trim($(this).text()).toLowerCase().indexOf(letter) == 0
        });
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(target).offset().top}, 1000);
    });


   $('#org_letterfilter').empty();
   reload_cart();


    $('#filters li').click(function (e) {
        console.log("click");
        $("#org_letterfilter a").removeClass("current");
        $('#org_letterfilter').empty();
        reload_cart();
    });


    $("#org_letterfilter").insertAfter( $("#filters") );


});
```

Comment: Posting code is a great start, but what we really need here to have the greatest chance of helping you is a [mcve]

Comment: @Jamiec I don't know from where the problem is coming from exactly, that's why I pasted it all... I load the function  reload_cart(); twice: on load and after "#filters li" click

Comment: And that is why creating an isolated example demonstrating the problem is helpful - first off you might work out exactly what the problem is, and if not we can see the issue and help you fix it.